# integration concening Fourier transfom variable and space variable

Tags: integration, analysis, fourier-analysis

We define the [short time Fourier transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-time_Fourier_transform) as follows:
$$V_{g}f(x,w)=\int_{\mathbb R} f(t)g(t-x)e^{-2\pi itw} dt, (x,w \in \mathbb R).$$

(We may assume that $f$ and $g$ nice functions so that every make sense)

**My Question is**: How $V_{g}f(x,w)$ and $V_{g}(-w, x)$
are related ? Is it true that $\mid V_{g}f(x,w)\mid= \mid V_{g}(-w,x)\mid  ?$

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $g$ has compact support, say $[-1,1]$. Then
$$\begin{align}
\phantom{-}V_{g}f(x,w)&=\int_{x-1}^{x+1}f(t)\,g(t-x)\,e^{-2\pi itw}\,dt,\\
V_{g}f(-x,w)&=\int_{-x-1}^{-x+1}f(t)\,g(t+x)\,e^{-2\pi itw}\,dt.
\end{align}
$$
If $|x|\ge1$, $V_{g}f(x,w)$ and $V_{g}f(-x,w)$ take into account values of $f$ on disjoint intervals, so that in general there is no relation between the two.